# MySQL - UNION select ordering first

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, union

I have SQL `SELECT` with `UNION (SELECT...)`

```
SELECT virtuemart_product_id 
FROM #__virtuemart_products 
WHERE product_special = 1
UNION
(SELECT virtuemart_product_id
 FROM #__virtuemart_product_badges
 WHERE badge = 3)
```

This select returns virtuemart_product_id:
`12345,54321,...,789,987` - for example last ids is from UNION (#__virtuemart_product_badges) tables.

I need to sort the results so that IDs from the `UNION` table are the first (`union_select_virtuemart_product_id` and after `first_select_virtuemart_product_id`).
If I try this:

```
...
UNION
    (SELECT virtuemart_product_id
     FROM #__virtuemart_product_badges AS badge
     WHERE badge = 3)
ORDER BY badge.virtuemart_product_id
```

result is error of course. Respectively any `ORDER BY` except `...ORDER BY virtuemart_product_id` ends with an error.

is this possible at all?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this. It creates an artificial value which indicates which table the data came from and then sorts by that value prior to the id value. By changing the value assigned to dataset and the sort order, you can change which values are output first:

```
(SELECT virtuemart_product_id, 0 AS dataset
FROM #__virtuemart_products 
WHERE product_special = 1)
UNION
(SELECT virtuemart_product_id, 1 AS dataset
 FROM #__virtuemart_product_badges
 WHERE badge = 3)
ORDER BY dataset DESC, virtuemart_product_id
```

**Edit**

Since there is a requirement to return only one column (`virtuemart_product_id`), you will need to wrap this query in a subquery and `SELECT virtuemart_product_id` from it:

```
SELECT virtuemart_product_id
FROM ((SELECT virtuemart_product_id, 0 AS dataset
       FROM #__virtuemart_products 
       WHERE product_special = 1)
      UNION
      (SELECT virtuemart_product_id, 1 AS dataset
       FROM #__virtuemart_product_badges
       WHERE badge = 3)
      ORDER BY dataset DESC, virtuemart_product_id) v
```

Comment: yes, but I did not realize (I apologize) that the result of the function must be only one column virtuemart_product_id :(

Comment: @LubosBelan the simplest way to achieve that is to wrap the query as a subquery. See my edit.

Comment: yes, maybe this is right way for my situation. thy very much :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result from the union table first then first select that table after that union another table. Like this:-

```
(SELECT virtuemart_product_id
 FROM #__virtuemart_product_badges
 WHERE badge = 3)
UNION
SELECT virtuemart_product_id 
FROM #__virtuemart_products 
WHERE product_special = 1
```

Comment: From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html): "UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows", so this won't work.

Comment: in SQL its works. but I dont know if I can use it in my code without having to edit it in bulk.

Comment: @LubosBelan although this may work in an example, it is not guaranteed to work. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try just make some nested query:

```
select * from (YOUR ALL QUERY) AS p order by virtuemart_product_id
```

Comment: can you tell me more about this? this syntax sort results by ID (asc, desc), or...no? I need sort results: union_select_virtuemart_productid, first_select_virtuemart_product_id

Comment: Sorry I was out. This is what Nick described (subquery) in their post https://stackoverflow.com/a/52242396/6357312